# Word 2007: Annotate picture with numbers?

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, graphics

I would like to annotate a bitmap picture with numbers. The numbers should simply be in the middle of circles with a solid white fill and a black border: ➀, ➁, ... Probably the numbers are only from 1 to 9, and definitely below 20.

What I tried (I'm using the German version of Word, so please excuse incorrect translation):

1. I created a new drawing area ("Zeichenbereich").
2. I added the bitmap to the drawing area.
3. I placed a flowchart node on top of the bitmap. Then I edited the text of that node and placed the number in the middle. Simple. But the result is not satisfying: The lower part of the number is clipped, although the circle is very large.

Is there a better solution?

If all else fails, naturally I will add the numbers to the image and export it at a high resolution. Only that will slow down the workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, instead of using a flowchart node, I am now using an ordinary circle (ellipse, drawn with shift). Seems that it is possible to add text to any shape. And, second, I found a way to adjust the position of the text within a shape:

1. With the shape selected, go to "Text Area Tools" / Format (translated from German).
2. Click the small icon next to "Font Size". A popup appears.
3. Switch to the tab "Text Area", and there you can adjust the position of the text.

If there is an easier solution, I'd like to hear about it. In that case I will make *your* answer the accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply added text to a circle, which it sounds like you did, edit the text again and reduce the font size.

Comment: As I wrote, the circles are already way bigger than the text. The numbers are clipped inside of the white area, not by the black border!

Comment: Now found out about the reason for the clipping. See my solution. Adjusting the size of the borders gets rid of the clipping.

Comment: @feklee You need to remove your solution from your question and post it as a separate answer.

Comment: Naturally. However, I have to wait eight hours to do that. That's the rule, for "new users".

Answer (score 0):

Much simpler if you just want the number around the image (for 0-10):

1. Add a caption to the picture (right click on picture and select 'Insert Caption')
2. Tick 'Exclude label from caption' so the caption becomes a text box with a single digit in it
3. Highlight the digit just placed in the text box and replace it (insert symbol) with a wingding of the number you want and set the font size appropriately.

[image: 1]

If you want the number to be *ON* the picture, just insert a text box in the document, set its background and outline to *No Color* and insert the symbol inside the text box - you can then position it where you want:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Before I posted the question I have in fact considered the second solution that you mention. However, as I wrote, the circle needs to have a white background with a black border. So this solution is not an option. At the moment I'm happy with the solution I posted!

Comment: OK, use the other set of number/circle symbols in the WIngdings font set

Comment: That won't do it. The fonts have just one color that can be changed. What I need, however, are two colors: black and white (and naturally a transparent background for the area outside the circle). But, as I said before you posted your reply, I found a solution that works. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use MS Visio and grab a screen shot of whatever sketch you require to annotate. Then annotate using Visio.

Note the methods above do not allow you to move the numbers freely around in MS Word. The numbers will simply appear as they would in a regular sentence.